# React Native - JSON value '27' of type NSNumber cannot be converted to NSString

Tags: react-native

I have an image coming in from an API.

This code does show anything

```
<Image source={image} style={styles.petImage}/>
```

This code shows the image but when I navigate away and come back and I get the error in the description.

```
<Image source={{uri: image}} style={styles.petImage}/>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you console log your image value?

Comment: Yes, here is the value: https://img-stage.petkey.org/resource/images/660000/660000/660952.jpg?w=800

Comment: And what about styles.petImage?